# How to create a agm-direction with multiples points?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have 10 points (west and south cood) and I need to create a unic agm-map with this points. The route must pass through all these points. But.... When I search I found origin and destination points. but... and the intermediary points?

```
 <agm-direction *ngIf="dir" [origin]="dir.origin" [destination]="dir.destination"></agm-direction>
```

I'm Using Angular 7. And the npm agm map

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called waypoints in [Google Maps Directions Service API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) which:

> allow you to calculate routes through additional locations, in which
>   case the returned route passes through the given waypoints.
>
> A `waypoint` consists of the following fields:
>
> - `location` (required) specifies the address of the waypoint.
> - `stopover` (optional) indicates whether this waypoint is a actual    stop on the route (true) or instead only a preference to route
>     through the indicated location (false). Stopovers are true by
>     default.

I guess you are utilizing [`Agm-Direction` component](https://github.com/explooosion/Agm-Direction) to draw a route, if so waypoints could be specified like this:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-direction [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination" [waypoints]="waypoints"></agm-direction>
</agm-map>


export class AppComponent {

  lat = 41.85;
  lng = -87.65;

  origin = { lat: 29.8174782, lng: -95.6814757 };
  destination = { lat: 40.6976637, lng: -74.119764 };
  waypoints = [
     {location: { lat: 39.0921167, lng: -94.8559005 }},
     {location: { lat: 41.8339037, lng: -87.8720468 }}
  ];
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-direction-demo-5kgnuh)

Comment: the demo is not working. Can you fix it so that i can see the demo